# create a 2 row menu in wordpress

Tags: menus, css

I am trying to split my menu in 2 rows by css but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

I need my menu to be like (http://4amedical.com/en/) website, but instead, my menu moves under the subheader area (https://www.nicandishan.com/index.php/main/)

I am using BeTheme and I have no special plugins for menu. The menu I'm trying to create is different from Mega Menu.
I have already added a new class to my menu items to split by level, but I don't know how to set their position and move level 2 items to second row using css.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You may wish to contact the theme author, or to try asking your question on StackOverflow. This site doesn't typically help with CSS-specific questions.

Comment: Thank you @WebElaine. I figured it out. it took some time though!